# strange JSON parsing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

It's supposed to be a mini pokedex app that contains pokemons. I'm having a lot of trouble parsing through this particular JSON....

```
{
count: 949,
next: null,
previous: null,
results: [
{
name: "bulbasaur",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
},
{
name: "ivysaur",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
},
{
name: "venusaur",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
},
{
name: "charmander",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"
},
{
name: "charmeleon",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"
},
{
name: "charizard",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"
},
{
name: "squirtle",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"
},
{
name: "wartortle",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"
},
{
name: "blastoise",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"
},
{
name: "caterpie",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"
},
{
name: "metapod",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"
},
```

from https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/

It's basically a JSON with multiple urls. The initial JSON holds some data an array of pokemon structs. I have no problem parsing through this one, but I don't even know where to start with the additional URL.

the first bit of given inner URL looks like this (the entire thing is huge)

```
{
abilities: [
{
ability: {
name: "chlorophyll",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/34/"
},
is_hidden: true,
slot: 3
},
{
ability: {
name: "overgrow",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/65/"
},
is_hidden: false,
slot: 1
}
],
base_experience: 64,
forms: [
{
name: "bulbasaur",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/"
}
],
game_indices: [
{
game_index: 1,
version: {
name: "white-2",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/22/"
}
},
{
game_index: 1,
version: {
name: "black-2",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/21/"
}
},
{
game_index: 1,
version: {
name: "white",
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/18/"
}
},
{
game_index: 1,
```

from https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/

The thing is, I only need to extract certain attributes from the second one. Not sure how to extract some and ignore others. This is what I have so far....

```
struct Pokedex: Decodable {
    let count: Int?
    let next: Bool?
    let previous: Bool?
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    lt url: String?
}

struct Pokemon : Decodable {
    let weight: Int?
    let height: Int?
}

struct endPokemon {
    let name: String
    let weight: Int
    let height: Int
}
```

(weight and height are in the second url but later down the page)

```
var pokemons = [Pokemon]()

    func loadJSON() {
        let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
        guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let pokedex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokedex.self, from: data)

                for pokemon in pokedex.results {
                    guard let jsonURL = pokemon.url else { return }
                    guard let newURL = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newURL) {(data, response, error) in
                        guard let data = data else { return }

                        do {
                            let load = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokemon.self, from: data)
                            self.pokemons.append(load)
                        } catch let jsonErr {
                            print("Error serializing inner JSON:", jsonErr)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print("Error serializing JSON: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
```

I'm not getting any errors running, but the pokemons array is empty.

Any thoughts??

Comment: Okay fixed. Thanks!

Comment: kind of! Why the first JSON is relevant is because I need to use that JSON to get create an array of all the pokemon. I'm just not sure what the best practice for achieving that is. It is perfectly fine to extract only certain things from a JSON response, correct? By not creating variables for them in the struct?

Comment: my last struct contains the values that I want to keep. Is my method of for looping through the URLs in the first JSON a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object types look fine. The only issue is not calling the `.resume()` on the inner `dataTask`. Check the corrected snippet below,

```
func loadJSON() {
    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
    guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let pokedex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokedex.self, from: data)

            for pokemon in pokedex.results {
                guard let jsonURL = pokemon.url else { return }
                guard let newURL = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newURL) {(data, response, error) in
                    guard let data = data else { return }

                    do {
                        let load = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokemon.self, from: data)
                        self.pokemons.append(load)
                    } catch let jsonErr {
                        print("Error serializing inner JSON:", jsonErr)
                    }
                }.resume()
            }
        } catch let jsonErr{
            print("Error serializing JSON: ", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! That definitely fixed somethings. Just to make sure that I understand this right, it is possible to only extract certain things from JSON and not all values is that correct? And what is the best way to create an array of pokemon, whose attributes are given by url in the first JSON response? I only need the name, weight and height, but name belongs to the first struct, whereas the other two are inside the other JSON response. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's completely fine to parse only the required values from the JSON. It looks fine to keep detail in an array as there is `name` and `id` attributes also along with `weight`, `height` in nested JSON so you can always relate objects in different arrays.

Comment: man, thanks so much! Last question, is there a better way to create the array than the way I'm doing it now? For looping over the original array that is